# Class variables not being initialized from constructor

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my Camera class contructor. I have lots of variables that I'm initializing in constructor and for all of them are assigned some garbade values instead of mine. Where might be the problem? For example `printf("%d", yawSensitivity)` outputs `-1610612736`

I've tried to paste as little code as possible. Maybe you will spot a concept error and point me in the right direction...

Camera.h

```
class Camera
{
    protected:

        int windowMidX;
        int windowMidY;

        float pitchSensitivity; 
        float yawSensitivity; 

    public:

        Camera(int windowWidth, int windowHeight);
        ~Camera();
};
```

Camera.cpp

```
Camera::Camera(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
{
    this->windowMidX = windowWidth  / 2;
    this->windowMidY = windowHeight / 2;

    this->pitchSensitivity = 0.1f; 
    this->yawSensitivity   = 0.1f;
}
Camera::~Camera() {}
```

Camera initialization

```
Camera *cam = new Camera(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example `printf("%d", yawSensitivity)`

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. `yawSensitivity` is of type `float`. `%d` format specifier expects a parameter of type `int`. Use `%f` instead.

Comment: To add to Igor's answer, the constructor is probably initializing just fine, but misusing `printf()` has caused the questioner to make an incorrect assumption about his code.  When in doubt, step through it with a debugger.